# What is the importance of eigenvalues in mathematics ? In the real world, where we use them?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, applications

What is the importance of eigenvalues in mathematics? In the real world, where do we use these eigenvalues?

Comment: What do you consider to be "the real world"? There are lots of applications of eigenvalues, but you may not think of all of them as real world applications. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors for lots of examples.

Comment: I edited "eigen value" to a single word because [of this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eigenvalue%2C+eigen+value&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: quantum mechanics for instance